# WPF Bind Rectangle Width and Height to Relative Source

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I m trying to bind my rectangle width and height to a slider that is in a different view/control.

I have a Main View that Loads 2 different Views.

1 of the Views has the slider control is named MainFooterView and the Slider control is named MainWindowSlider

In the Other View a have a Rectangle that I want to bind the value of the slider to the Width and Height of that Rectangle but is not working, any Ideas how to do this?

```
<Rectangle Fill="Aqua"
Width="{Binding MainWindowSlider.Value, Mode=OneWay, 
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainFooterView}}}" 

Height="{Binding MainWindowSlider.Value, Mode=OneWay, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainFooterView}}}"
                               />
```

Thank you.

UPDATE
[image]

[image]

Comment: At the time the rectangle is rendered/shown, where does the slider's view/control sit in the visual tree in relation to the rectangle?  Or put another way, does the slider control sit above or below the rectangle in the XAML tree.  Can you show the declaration of the slider control also.

Comment: The view that has the slider in it sits at the same level as the view that has the rectangle, but the slider view is show (in the visual tree)  below the view that has the rectangle

Comment: See my answer, which I'll post now.

Comment: ElementName  does not work in this case, would only work if I had the Slider in the same view where the rectangle is at, but my case is not.

Comment: Are you trying to bind to something which isn't actually in the rendered/visible visual tree?  That will never work ...

Comment: The rectangles are visible, if I manually set the height and width they show  correctly.

Comment: I'm talking about whether the SliderControl is visible.  I thought you were binding the rectangle width/height to the width/height of the slider control?  I'm asking this - is the slider control on the same window as the rectangle when you show it and the ElementName solutiuon doesn't work?

Comment: If I place the slider control in the same view has where the rectangle is at, using the ElementName everything works fine

Comment: Ok, the crux here is how these views relate.  I haven't yet been able to determine whether both are visible and in the same visual tree at the same time ... you can't bind to something that isn't in the visual tree because it has no width or height.

Comment: Ok, I made a visual image of the tree, you were right the there s one more view nested inside, please have a look...

Comment: Image uploaded again... Sorry

Comment: Anyone?........

Comment: Both views should share a view model with an appropriate property, e.g. `public double RectSize`. Search the web for MVVM.

Comment: @J_PT ... I'll update my answer and show you comparable XAML that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your full XAML and this may not answer the exact question, so I've used a regular "Slider" control here and given the *instance* of it a name for binding-to.  If you use AncestorType it is dependent upon upward visual tree recursion (i.e. it looks for parents, not children), but this solution binds the width of an element to the width of a 'sibling' element.

Here is the XAML for the slider control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UCSlider"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Slider Width="700"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

... and for the rectangle control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UCRectangle"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="PaleGreen" Height="50" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then when both are brought into the Main Window:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:UCRectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Slider1}"/>
    <local:UCSlider x:Name="Slider1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as written. Did you actually try it? Plus, while I was trying to do the same thing, I realized that it is just bad design in general. This represents a tight coupling between user controls which really should be avoided. (It is a maintenance nightmare if your user controls get entangled in this way.) Common model view is the way to go.

Comment: Yep this was tried and worked, you might need to look a little closer at the OP's scenario - he is dealing with two different visual trees.  Post up your solution and let's take a look.

Comment: I created a brand new wpf solution, added two user controls called View1 and View2, and pasted your code snippets as is (along with standard Window boiler-plate for MainWindow). I expected the width of green box to correspond to the slider, but it is unresponsive -- it simply fills the entire top cell of the main window grid. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok so I think you're missing the point a little - it's not supposed to be responsive and dynamically change width based on the slider - rather it is supposed to create the rectangle with the ActualWidth of the slider.   I've updated to contain the correct names and bindings.